# get a reuse the token for the Huawei modem E3372h

Tags: python-3.x

so i want to read some sms received in my huawei modem.

For that i m tryin to first get the token and session id from the  'http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/SesTokInfo page

then try to reuse this token in the page http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/sms-list

but i got this error

```
<error>
<code>125002</code>
<message></message>
</error>
```

which mean that i don t have the right token value, what i m wondering about.

so this is how my code looks

```
import hashlib
import base64
import binascii
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASEURL = 'http://192.168.8.1'


session = requests.Session()
reqresponse = session.get(BASEURL + '/api/webserver/SesTokInfo')
if reqresponse.status_code == 200:
        root = ET.fromstring(reqresponse.text)
        for results in root.iter('SesInfo'):
            sessionid = results.text
            print("the sessionId is", sessionid)
        for results in root.iter('TokInfo'):
            token = results.text
            print("The token is", token)
        sessioncookies = reqresponse.cookies

post_data = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>\n'
post_data += '<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>3</ReadCount><BoxType>1</BoxType><SortTyp$

headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
               '__RequestVerificationToken': token
              }

api_url = BASEURL + '/api/sms/sms-list'
logonresponse = session.post( api_url, data=post_data, headers=headers, cookies=sessioncookies)
logonresponse2 = session.get( api_url, data=post_data, headers=headers, cookies=sessioncookies)




result = BeautifulSoup(logonresponse.text, 'html.parser')

for r in result:
    print(r)
```

can someone helo me with the troubleshooting please?